# Zeppelin Rspark

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm trying to install Zeppelin on Windows. I was using this guide:
https://hernandezpaul.wordpress.com/2016/11/14/apache-zeppelin-installation-on-windows-10/

But when I try to use R i get error massage:

```
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: sparkr is not responding 
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinR.waitForRScriptInitialized(ZeppelinR.java:285)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinR.request(ZeppelinR.java:227)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinR.eval(ZeppelinR.java:176)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.ZeppelinR.open(ZeppelinR.java:165)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.spark.SparkRInterpreter.open(SparkRInterpreter.java:90)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.open(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:70)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:491)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.FIFOScheduler$1.run(FIFOScheduler.java:139)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Do you know what is wrong?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi, I haven't used zeppelin in windows 10, but I think you can try dockerized version. `docker run -p 8080:8080 --rm -v $PWD/logs:/logs -v $PWD/notebook:/notebook -e ZEPPELIN_LOG_DIR='/logs' -e ZEPPELIN_NOTEBOOK_DIR='/notebook' --name zeppelin apache/zeppelin:0.7.2`

Comment: @1lambda I have proble executing this line. "System cannot find file specified".

Comment: Let's try this one without many options. `docker run -p 8080:8080 apache/zeppelin:0.7.2` If you fail to run this command, u need to install [docker for windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/).

Comment: The line is working but I get to the point where it stops(not error). How long shoud it take to execute to the end?

Comment: Usually the homepage (localhost:8080) would up in 1 min. (I am using macbook pro 2017). Did u access to localhost:8080 in the chrome browser?

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you

Comment: my final comment is since docker doesn't persist any files when it's finished, u need to persist using docker the volume option `-v`. (because I am not a windows user, currently I don't know proper command.. sorry for that)